# crontab has been corrupted? @^@^@^@^@^ after clone

Tags: centos, cron

So I have created the following cronjob to run after the VM clones first boot

```
@reboot sleep 30 && sudo bash /root/first.sh
@reboot sleep 30 && sudo bash /root/first2.sh
```

However after I clone the VM and boot it back up the scripts don't run and `crontab -e` shows the following

[image]

I am doing the same process on CentOS 6/Ubuntu 14.04 / Ubuntu 16.04 with no problem. Only CentOS 7 is causing an issue.

Comment: yes, those are probably `NUL` characters. as to how they got there, we'd need to know a lot more about your process

Comment: The scripts? If so I don't think it's them. The screenshot taken was within the first 30 seconds of boot.

Comment: There's a whole lot of missing information that this question assumes that we telepathically have, starting with "the" VM clone.  There's no information about how this clone operation was done, not even how the machine was shut down in order to clone it.

Comment: `NUL` characters. So the filesystem metadata is there, but the actual data is not. Are you cloning filesystems of an active VM without at least a minimal "flush buffers and quiesce" procedure first? Note that CentOS 7 has XFS as a default filesystem type, unlike CentOS 6 and probably the Ubuntus: your cloning procedure may need some tweaking for it.